# Tikz: setting anchors for all paths

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to force all paths in a part of a drawing to use a specific anchor for all the nodes they connect, and was hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
\begin{scope}[every path/.style={anchor=south}]
    \draw (a) -- (b);
\end{scope}
```

instead of the obvious but tedious

```
\draw (a.south) -- (b.south);
```

However the above will only affect nodes that I create as I draw the path (e.g. `\draw (a) -- node {text} (b);`. How can I achieve what I wanted?

Comment: As far as I know, path doesn't have anchors. They are defined only for nodes and named according to node shape.  Saying `\draw (a) -- (b)` with assumption that (a) and (b) are names of nodes , means that line will lie between  those nodes' borders with start and end in its center (as you notice, I guess).  I'm afraid that here is no other options to define  coordinates  which you like to connect by lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(<node name>.<anchor name>)` syntax is a reference to an **existing** node anchor. It doesn't create a new node. Hence placement has already been done as Zarko mentioned.

Instead you can use a to path

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[so/.style={to path={(\tikztostart.south)--(\tikztotarget.south)\tikztonodes}}]
\node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {A};
\node[draw] (b) at (1,1) {B};
\draw[so] (a) to (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

using whatever path spec you would like to have in between.

Comment: nice solution, unfortunately limited to very limited syntax for connection of nodes: `--` or `-|` works as without option `so`.

Comment: @Zarko You can go as complicated as you wish. It's just a demo. For me (a.south) is pretty OK.

Comment: I agree with you.